# Removing trailing zeros and decimal point in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
val
4.20
4.00
```

I would like to remove the trailing zeros and the decimal point if there are no additional decimals. Thus, my desired end result is

```
val
4.2
4
```

I know that I can use `str_remove` to get rid of the trailing zeros, but I am left with the decimal point on the 4. How can I update this code to drop that decimal point?

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(val = c("4.20", "4.00")) %>% 
  mutate(val = str_remove(val, "0+$"))
```

Edit: The numbers must be stored as a character.

Edit 2: Figured out solution below. Since data is stored as a character, solution needs to be robust to other instances in which you might deal with regular old character strings etc. This function deals with all contingencies:

```
decimal_func <- function(x) {
  decimalVal_check <- function(y) {
    case_when(str_count(y, "\\.") <= 1 & str_detect(str_replace(y, "\\.", ""), "^[:digit:]+$") == T ~ "Valid", TRUE ~ "Invalid")
  }
  if(decimalVal_check(x) == "Valid") {
    if(str_count(x, "\\.") == 0) {
      x
    } else {
      str_remove(x, "0+$") %>% 
        ifelse(substr(., nchar(.), nchar(.)) == ".", str_replace(., "\\.", ""), .)
    } 
  } else {
    x
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `data.frame(val = c("4.20", "4.00")) %>%
  type.convert(as.is  =TRUE) %>%
  as_tibble()
`

Comment: Unfortunately with the actual use case that wouldn't work. Good idea though!

Comment: Why won't it work?

Comment: `data.frame(val = c("4.20", "4.00")) %>%   type.convert(as.is  =TRUE) %>%   as_tibble()%>%mutate(across(everything(), as.character))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
data.frame(val = c("4.20", "4.00")) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is  =TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(val = as.character(val))

# A tibble: 2 x 1
  val  
  <chr>
1 4.2  
2 4
```

Using `str_remove`:

```
data.frame(val = c("4.20", "4.00")) %>%  
  mutate(val = str_remove(val, '\\.?0+$'))

  val
1 4.2
2   4
```

Any of the following can work:

```
formatC(c(1,2.40,5.06), zero.print = "")
[1] "1"    "2.4"  "5.06"
prettyNum(c(1,2.40,5.06), zero.print = "")
[1] "1"    "2.4"  "5.06"
prettyNum(c(1,2.40,5.06), drop0trailing = TRUE)
[1] "1"    "2.4"  "5.06"
formatC(c(1,2.40,5.06), drop0trailing = TRUE)
[1] "1"    "2.4"  "5.06"
```

Comment: Thanks so much. One issue on your final solution - those all take inputs that are numeric in nature, where mine needs to be character. I found that this solution works: 

data.frame(val = c("4.20", "4.00")) %>%  
  mutate(val = str_remove(val, '\\.?0+$'))

Except when you feed it a number like 70, where it just cuts off the 0 and leaves you with 7. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: for all the rest, just change the column to numeric using `as.numeric` and then apply the code. @DJC

Comment: Wish I could but has to stay character for the actual business case. It's annoying, I know but can't get around it

Comment: Posted my solution above.

Comment: @DJC you mean you cannot do `as.character(formatC(as.numeric(val), drop0trailing = TRUE))`?? This will keep your column as character

Comment: Nope. Try pass 'James4' into that. You get an error. Because of the way the actual use case works, you'll have instances in which you have both letters and numbers so the solution has to be robust to those instances. That's why my solution that I came up with first checks if (1) there is only a single decimal and (2) aside from the decimal, all other values are numbers. If both of those conditions are satisfied, then it performs the rest of the steps, if either one of those conditions is not satisfied, then it returns the original value

Comment: @DJC you never mentioned that, neither did you include that in your original post. If that is the case, you could use `sub` + `grepl` to get around easily

Comment: You're right. This wasn't my best reprex. Apologies for the confusion.